# How to implement a global WinAPI overlay interface

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

We need to implement a universal autocomplete for users at our company. Basically when someone starts with # and then types a name, we want to help them with autocomplete options (some sort of list showing).

This needs to work in any application in windows.

The plan is capture all keypresses, look for the # character, and if they have typed that start helping them with the autocomplete. If they select an option then we SendKeys the rest of the name down to the current cursor location, thereby finishing the name for them.

We have the keypress part working, but we aren't sure how to display the autocomplete feature. How can we implement a UI for this with the Win32 API?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use raw Win32 API for your UI?  C# already gives you multiple GUI frameworks (WinForms, WPF), any of which can serve your purpose.  I mean, it's a horribly bad idea (if I were at your company, I would need to be able to type `#define` and `#include` without triggering your list of names), but it is very possible.

Comment: And I feel very sorry for any of your users who have a `#` character in a password...

Comment: Haha thanks Ben. This is an example, it's not EXACTLY what we are doing. So we don't need critique on the exact implementation put forward, just help implementing it. Thanks though.

Comment: What's wrong with making a window (WinForms or WPF) and setting its location to be exactly adjacent to the window which received the keypress of interest?  You *can* make a UI with raw WinAPI, but it won't be easier.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think that's what I have to do. I've started to work on that and so far so good. Thanks for the tip. Problem I'm having right now is finding the location of where the user is typing...I know how to get the cursor (pointer) location (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos), but not the window and where they are typing location...

Comment: Try `GetGUIThreadInfo` for getting the window with focus, if your keyboard hook didn't provide that information.

Comment: That only works for GUI widgets, that are actually backed by native windows. That's a fraction of controls you'll ever see. It won't work for any kind of window-less control (Qt applications, browsers, UWP applications, WPF applications, etc.). Long story short, what you are trying to accomplish is not possible unless you are willing to sacrifice reliability, and put in a **LOT** of work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit controls have the [IAutoComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and you can also use [UWP TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox) and [AutoSuggestBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox).

Comment: How do I show that control in any application, whereever the user is typing (notepad, a browser, outlook, word, etc.) This needs to be global.

Comment: What do you mean in any application. Do you want this control to be attached to other applications?

Comment: Anywhere (any application) the user types the # keyword, we want to start helping them autocomplete.

Comment: Impossible, unless you create a dll that attaches to all processes (APPINIT_Dlls) and subclass all the text inputs, which is bound to create problems.

Comment: What's impossible? I already can capture every keypress. I just don't know how to present a ui...

Comment: You can present an UI (stealing the focus from the input), the trouble is how to move your input to the target application.

Comment: That's easy. WinApi has sendkeys